# Can I eliminate the inner query from my query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to know if I can improve this query:

```
SELECT _c.*,
       _o.Status,
      (SELECT TOP 1 _o.PlacedOn
         FROM Orders _o1
         JOIN Client _c1 on _c1.Id = _o1.Client_Id
        WHERE _c1.Id = 3
     ORDER BY PlacedOn DESC) as LastOrderDate
  FROM Client _c
  JOIN Orders _o on _c.[Id] = _o.[Client_Id]
 WHERE _c.Id = 3 AND _o.[Status] = 'Draft'
```

The outer JOIN is needed in order to get information from client and also some information on he's order.

The inner JOIN, gets the last placed order of that client.

I would like to know if I can remove the inner join and how.

```
           Client.tbl
Id              int
Gender          nvarchar(255)
DateOfBirth     nvarchar(255)
ContactDetails  nvarchar(MAX)
FirstName       nvarchar(255)
MiddleName      nvarchar(255)
LastName        nvarchar(255)


           Order.tbl
Id                int
Status            nvarchar(255)
PaymentMethod     nvarchar(255)
PlacedOn          datetime2(7)
CancelledOn       datetime2(7)
PaidOn            datetime2(7)
OrderNumber       nvarchar(255)
Client_Id         int
```

Client test data:

```
Id  Gender  DateOfBirth ContactDetails  FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
1     F.    10/16/1991       NULL          Mia        M.          Brown
```

Order test data:

```
Id  Status  PaymentMethod  PlacedOn  CancelledOn  PaidOn  OrderNumber  Client_Id
1   Done       Cash       11/11/1996    NULL       NULL     NULL           1
2   Done       Cash       11/11/2007    NULL       NULL     NULL           1
3   Draft      NULL          NULL       NULL       NULL     NULL           1
```

Expected result:

1. client information FirstName for example
2. the Id of order where status is 'Draft'
3. the PlacedOn where its value is max, so in this case 11/11/2007

Result:

```
FirstName    DraftId     LastPlacedOn
   Mia          3         11/11/2007
```

Comment: sure, just a sec

Comment: If you can detail the expected result, it would be better. Now, things that I can recommend you to optimize your query is to evaluate the execution plan and the statistics, with this you can guide the consumption of resources, necessary indices and identify where your bottleneck is.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you can use `MAX() OVER ()` to find the maximum value from the result set:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT _c.*, 
           _o.Status,
           MAX(_o.PlacedOn) OVER (PARTITION BY _c.id) as LastOrderDate
     FROM Client _c
     JOIN Orders _o on _c.[Id] = _o.[Client_Id]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE Id = 1 AND [Status] = 'Draft'
```

Comment: adding `AND _o.[Status] = 'Draft'` makes it not work well. I mean, I get LastOrderDate as null. I guess it first executed the select and only then it applies the max operation on the result set

Comment: Yes I was afraid you wanted the max date from unfiltered result. I have revised my answer but perhaps your original query was better.